# how to prevent a user does not turn back to a page by using back button of browser after log out

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can i prevent browser using the cached copy of the page after log out ?

When user logged out still they can access the previous pages by using the back button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security 3.2 (or later), you can specify the following in your security namespace configuration:

```
<http>
  <headers>
    <cache-control/>
  </headers>
  ...
</http>
```

This will set the necessary headers in responses stopping the browser from caching the pages in the webapp.